# starting jetty 9 faild ubuntu 12.04

Tags: jetty, ubuntu-12.04

i installed jetty (distribution-9.0.2) on ubuntu server 12.04
from these links step by step

http://degreesofzero.com/article/19

http://pietervogelaar.nl/ubuntu-12-04-install-jetty-9/

at last when i start jetty with the following command:

```
sudo /etc/init.d/jetty start
```

or

```
sudo service jetty start
```

i get the following error

```
Starting Jetty: grep: /var/run/jetty.state: No such file or directory
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm facing with the same problem but on Debian 6 server. Workaround for this problem and articles above, from my perspective, is:

1. use **JETTY_ARGS=jetty.port=8080** instead **JETTY_PORT**
2. Add property to /etc/init.d/jetty: **JETTY_PID=/opt/jetty/jetty.state**

Please, let me know if you have any questions

Comment: tanQ evgeniy,i add jetty_pid but i get another error just telling start fails,,but then i run this bash [bash --debugger ./jetty start] and jetty starts with no error,,after that [jetty start] works fine

Answer (score 0):

I've tested this thoroughly with the latest release of jetty and it's working fine. There's been some changes recently in the jetty.sh script. However the changes look good to me and it's working fine for me with the latest release.

Evgenly is right, that JETTY_PORT is deprecated (see comments in jetty.sh for details), however it also works fine for me using JETTY_PORT instead of JETTY_ARGS to define a non standard port.

Please try the latest release from here in case you didn't do already:
http://download.eclipse.org/jetty/

If jetty.sh reports that the start failed, you'll usually find the reason in stderrout.log inside the JETTY_HOME/logs directory (unless you've changed the logging config).